# Retrieving a file list from a remote file system with Node.js

Tags: javascript, web-applications, node.js, webos

Is it possible to retrieve a directory listing of a remote file-system using Node.js. I know how to do it locally using readdir(...) or readdirSync(...) but can I use those methods to return a list of remote files especially from a http or ftp server?

EDIT:
I want to do this in webOS so I'm limited to the supported API's it seems. I may have to do some real round-a-bout method like have a script that creates a file that contains a list of files in the folder and just accessing that. So I guess that brings up a second question could I fire a remote script from a local script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You could find an ftp client for node, then if your server has an ftp server going you can just interact with it.

**The following is how you might go about getting real filesystem access to a remote server**

If you have root access to the remote machine you are trying to interact with, yes it should be possible. Otherwise, no.

I am not super familiar with all of this, but you will need to do something along the lines of:

1. Configure a Network File System server (something like [this](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/ar01s02.html#whatis_nfs)) on your remote machine.
2. Set up an NFS client on your local machine where node is being run and mount the network file system.
3. Then ***i think***, you should be able to use the node filesystem library to browse the network file system mounted locally as you would with the normal file system.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to have to play with this. For now I'm just having a daemon running on the server that generates a list of files for me.

Answer (score 2):

You may want [jsDav](https://github.com/mikedeboer/jsdav) and [node-ftp](https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp).